# How to enumerate the scanner list in LAN using C#

Tags: c#, twain

We are developing a web application in which we need to detect all the scanner connect to LAN for scanning images. We are using twain classes to scan images. We are looking methods as below to get all the scanner from LAN.

TWAINXCLib.TwxScan scanner = new TWAINXCLib.TwxScan();

int scannerCount = scanner.GetScannerCount(wndHandle);

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Are the drivers for the scanner installed on the client PC you are working on?  Because that's how TWAIN works...

Comment: Look at the ARP table in the PC using cmd.exe with command >ARP -A.  The ARP table gets filled from the periodic ARP Request that is sent from an LAN device. The ARP table contains the MAC for the device which contains the Manufacturer ID, the Device Part NO, and Device Serial Number. ARP messages are Multicast and will get blocked by routers/servers.  If the device is on the other side of a Router you can ping the device which also fills the ARP table.  I have ping all 256 IP addresses in the subnet to find a device with specific MAC numbers.